# Special bank account required for a LLC?

Tags: united-kingdom, bank-account, accounting, limited-liability-company

I've just incorporated my first LLC in the UK. I'm now looking to open a new bank account to keep my personal finances and the business finances separate.

Could I sign up for say a regular Halifax current account using my name and then use that for the LLC, or does it need to be a special account which I can register in the business name?

Answer (score 1):

As an LLC you are required to have a separate bank account (so you can't have one account and mix personal and business finances together as you could if you were a sole trader) - but there's no requirement for it to be a business bank account.

However, the terms and conditions of most high street bank personal current accounts specifically exclude business banking, so unless you could find one that would allow it, you'd have to open a business bank account.